# Backbone: Different views for different tab content

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js

I have a generic view and 4 other views. I am using bootstrap tabs (nav-tabs) in the generic view. I want the other 4 views to be the content of 4 tabs in the generic view.
As I am new to backbone and bootstrap I am not able to figure out how to do that. Also, I am using only views in backbone for now (which means, there is no model or controller).
Would sure appreciate the idea of how to do this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest breaking things down.

1st you build your bootstrap HTML for your tabs and give a unique selector to each one of them. For instance, on this file here https://gist.github.com/mnewt/4228037 :

```
<ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#red" data-toggle="tab">Red</a></li>
    <li><a href="#orange" data-toggle="tab">Orange</a></li>
    <li><a href="#yellow" data-toggle="tab">Yellow</a></li>
    <li><a href="#green" data-toggle="tab">Green</a></li>
    <li><a href="#blue" data-toggle="tab">Blue</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="red">
        <h1>Red</h1>
        <p>red red red red red red</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="orange">
        <h1>Orange</h1>
        <p>orange orange orange orange orange</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="yellow">
        <h1>Yellow</h1>
        <p>yellow yellow yellow yellow yellow</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="green">
        <h1>Green</h1>
        <p>green green green green green</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="blue">
        <h1>Blue</h1>
        <p>blue blue blue blue blue</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

2nd now you can create your 4 content views passing `el` as the id for each content tab:

```
var tab1 = new ContentView({
   el: '#red'
});
var tab2 = new ContentView({
   el: '#orange'
});
var tab3 = new ContentView({
   el: '#yellow'
});
var tab4 = new ContentView({
   el: '#green'
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! :)
But then, I have 4 views which has their corresponding HTML element. So I want those views with their corresponding HTML element to render in the given tabs.

Comment: In this case you can use a HTML template inside your View. You may create 4 views consuming different templates.

Comment: To be more specific, to start you may try Underscore templates, or Handlebars, both are pretty straight forward. One example here: https://gist.github.com/kyleondata/3440492

Answer (score 0):

I approached this differently using css driven tabs based on [this](http://codepen.io/wallaceerick/pen/ojtal).

The idea is to have it so that the css will handle the hiding and displaying of tabs. The js just simply listens for which tab is clicked and renders the view accordingly.

For example, the following could be the html which defines the tab structure and the containers which will hold each view. Html:

```
<div>
    <ul id="profileMainView" class="tabs">
        <li class="labels" >
            <label class="profile-selectTab selectedTab" for="tab0" id="profile-label0">
                Tab 0
            </label>
            <label class="profile-selectTab" for="tab1" id="profile-label1">
                Tab 1
            </label>
            <label class="profile-selectTab" for="tab2" id="profile-label2">
                Tab 2
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<ul class="tabs">
    <li>
        <input type="radio" checked name="tabs" id="tab0">
        <div id="tab-content0" class="tab-content">
            Tab 1 Content
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab1">
        <div id="tab-content1" class="tab-content">
            Tab 2 Content
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab2">
        <div id="tab-content2" class="tab-content">
            Tab 3 Content
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This css can handle hiding and showing the tabs:

```
.tabs input[type=radio] {
    display:none;
}

.tabs {
    float: none;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.tabs li {
    display: block;
}

.labels{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
    height: 55px;
}

.labels:after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

[id^=tab]:checked ~ div[id^=tab-content] {
    display: block;
}

[id^=tab]:checked ~ div[id^=tab-content] {
     display: block;
}
```

Finally the js can just listen for which tab is selected and then render the view by passing in the id of the selected tab:

```
var mainView = Backbone.View.extend({
     events: {
        'click .profile-selectTab' : function(e) {
            this.renderTab(e.currentTarget.id);
     },
     renderTab: function(id){
         if(id == 'profile-label0'){
             yourView1.render('tab-content0');
         } else if(id == 'profile-label1'){
             yourView2.render('tab-content1');
         } else if(id == 'profile-label2'){
             yourView3.render('tab-content2');
         }
     }
});
```

Each view would just render and append to the correct tab's div. For example:

```
var yourView1 = Backbone.View.extend({
    render : function(targetDiv){
        $('#' + targetDiv).append(...);
    }
});
```